# arrange output to look like tabular column wise in linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed

please help to arrange the output to look like a tabular format by adding white space where needed. below is my output, where i am not able to add white space.in 2nd , 3rd and 4th line.

```
 a m  p  luo        16              8192            /dev/dsk/c0t5000C50039FFA34Dd0s7
 a    p  luo        8208            8192            /dev/dsk/c0t5000C50039FFA34Dd0s7
 a    p  luo        16              8192            /dev/dsk/c0t5000C5003A003295d0s7
 a    p  luo        16              8192            /dev/dsk/c0t5000C5003A003295d0s7
```

in the above output i need to add white space below 'm' so that my output can be in tabular format. however when i apply awk it seems like this.

```
 awk -F" " '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}'

a m p luo 16
a p luo 8208
a p luo 16
a p luo 8208
```

Please help

Comment: Not sure how you got five fields in first line `a m p luo 16` although you printed four fields !! ??

Comment: my bad `awk -F" " '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}'`

Comment: Are you sure ?? because the bottom 4 lines have 4 fields but now you're suggesting 5 fields ?  I believe you want to use `FS` as something more than one space to get the output you've shown here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the output you desire, use this `awk`

```
$ awk -v FS="[[:space:]][[:space:]]+" -v OFS="\t" '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}' file
 a m    p       luo     16
 a      p       luo     8208
 a      p       luo     16
 a      p       luo     16
```

`FS="[[:space:]][[:space:]]+"` field separator is consecutive spaces
`OFS="\t"` Output field separator is tab

Comment: in Lilnux its working well , if i am do it on Solaris SunOS, getting an error `awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1`

Comment: @Prayag, it is sun os, check my solution on same.

Comment: @Prayag that error message means you're trying to use old, broken awk which unfortunately is the default awk on Solaris. Use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk instead.